# Java Swing rendering Issue (Empty spaces & doubled rendering)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, rendering

i have a little rendering issue with java swing's JFrame / JPanel.
I want to render a line on my self so i've created a method to render many points with the Graphics g and its working pretty fine (on my second monitor).
Now i am using my main laptop monitor and i get cursed things:
[Rendering Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxTo9.png)

It should be just one continuesly line, but it has these little annoying gaps and its shown twice... that doesnt happen with my other (bigger) monitor but i guess thats shoudnt be like this (that its just working with some monitors). So the code is fine (i guess) and my monitors are also... :- Can you help me?
Thanks for answering guys :)

```
CODE ON PASTEBIN:

https://pastebin.com/kBVSjpCA
https://pastebin.com/svuhSXGw
https://pastebin.com/ftga7v2L
https://pastebin.com/fHtYj35G
https://pastebin.com/zA0N1LqE
```

Comment: Without your code we could never know what's wrong. Create a [mcve] and the community will be able to help you.

Comment: Code on pastebin available... Links in the post :)

Comment: An [mre] should be posted with the question, not on pastebin. The code should be in a single class that we can copy/paste/compile and test, just like the example from Gilbert below.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a nifty tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  The part of the tutorial that covers custom drawing is [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

This is a Swing drawing example I whipped up for an earlier question.

[image: Drawing Example]

The general idea is to create a `JFrame` and create a separate drawing `JPanel`.  The drawing `JPanel` will extend `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method.

The first line of the `paintComponent` method must be a call to the `super` `paintComponent` method.  After that, you can use any `Graphics` or `Graphics2D` methods you want.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawingPanelExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawingPanelExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Empty Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 300));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
            super.paintComponent(pen);

            pen.drawRect(50, 50, 20, 20);
            pen.drawRect(100, 50, 40, 20);
            pen.drawOval(200, 50, 20, 20);
            pen.drawOval(250, 50, 40, 20);
            pen.drawString("Square", 50, 90);
            pen.drawString("Rectangle", 100, 90);
            pen.drawString("Circle", 200, 90);
            pen.drawString("Oval", 250, 90);
            pen.fillRect(50, 100, 20, 20);
            pen.fillRect(100, 100, 40, 20);
            pen.fillOval(200, 100, 20, 20);
            pen.fillOval(250, 100, 40, 20);
            pen.drawLine(50, 150, 300, 150);
            pen.drawArc(50, 150, 200, 100, 0, 180);
            pen.fillArc(100, 175, 200, 75, 90, 45);
        }
        
    }

}
```